# Flow control problems while waiting for user feedback from a dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using javascript and a jquery dialog box to confirm that a user wants to proceed before the web client queries the server for some data.

```
$("#get_stories").click(function(){
    if (userConfirms()){
      getStories()  //call routine to load and process stories
    } else {
      alert("Not getting any stories")
    };
    return false;
});


var userConfirms = function(){
  var $dialog = $("#dialogBox");
  $dialog.html("Are you sure?")
  $dialog.dialog("option", "buttons", 
    [
        {
            text: "Proceed",
            click: function(){
                $dialog.dialog("close");
                return true
            }
        },
        {
            text: "Cancel",
            click: function(){
                $dialog.dialog("close");
                return false
            }
        }
    ]
  );
  $dialog.dialog("open");
};
```

What is happening is that the get_stories click event is triggering, userConfirms() is being called to check for true/false, the dialog opens so to get the user's feedback, but before the user clicks "Proceed" or "Cancel", control flows through to the alert statement.  How can I make the function triggered by the original click event wait for the user's feedback before continuing execution?

Thanks!

Comment: Why dont you put `getStories()` inside the `click` function in `userConfirms()` ?

Comment: I could do that, but I was hoping to re-use `userConfirms()` for other situations that required user feedback, not just for `getStories()`

Comment: The problem is that `userConfirms()` always return true, it will not wait for the user to click `confirm` or `cancel`

Comment: That's what I figured.  javascript confirmation boxes, however, pause execution while waiting for user feedback.  So, there must be a way to do what I'm trying to do with jquery dialog boxes.

Comment: Then your solution is to use a callback like `userConfirms = function(onSucess, onCancel) { .....`, then `click: function() { $.isFunction(onSucess) && onSucess() ....`

Comment: One of these days I'm going to no longer be a noob.  You are right that passing in callback functions solves my problem.  BTW, after I saw your comment I read this blog to flesh-out the concept of creating my own callbacks: http://www.impressivewebs.com/callback-functions-javascript/

Comment: @RodrigoAssis if you would like to submit your comment as an answer I will go ahead and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

userConfirms() will always return `true`, the solution is to use a callback

```
var userConfirms = function(onSuccess, onCancel) { .....
```

Then on click function (both cancel and success)

```
click: function() { $.isFunction(onSuccess) && onSuccess() ....
```

And just call like this

```
userConfirms(callbackForSuccess, callbackForCancel)
```